How to ensure object values are keys of a type deduced by the object key with TypeScript?
Given
// GIVEN

type Animal<T extends string> = {
    id: T,
}

type Dog = Animal<"animal.dog"> & {
   foo: string
}

type Cat = Animal<"animal.cat"> & {
   bar: string
}

type MyType<T extends Dog | Cat = Dog | Cat> = { [K in T["id"]]: keyof T };

type MyTypeVariant<C extends "animal.dog" | "animal.cat" = "animal.dog" | "animal.cat"> = { [K in C]: keyof Animal<C> };

// EXPECT TO BE OK

const obj: MyType = {
    "animal.dog": "foo",
    "animal.cat": "bar"
}

// EXPECT TO FAIL

const fail: MyType = {
    "animal.dog": "bar",
    "animal.cat": "foo"
}

How can I create a type that would raise an error if the value (ex: "foo") is not a key of Type (ex: Cat), Type that can be deduced from the key (ex: "animal.cat") of obj?
For now I get the error

Type '"foo"' is not assignable to type '"id"'

Because "id" is the only property in common between Dog & Cat.
I guess I would need type inference here.
Any ideas?

Again, does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Absolutely! Yes, I would appreciate an answer to explain the as T["id"] part with maybe a link to the doc. Thanks a lot!

I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

The type you're looking for is
type Type =
  { [T in Dog | Cat as T["id"]]: keyof T }

which evaluates to
type Type = {
    "animal.dog": "id" | "foo";
    "animal.cat": "id" | "bar";
}

This uses key remapping in mapped types to iterate over the union Dog | Cat, and for each member T of that union, we use T["id"] as the key, and keyof T as the value.  Since we're iterating over the members of T, then the correlation between key and value is preserved.

If we needed to do it your way, where we iterate K over T["id"] instead of T, we'd need to check K and Extract the right member of T, perhaps like this:
type TypeGen<T extends Dog | Cat = Dog | Cat> =
  { [K in T["id"]]: keyof Extract<T, { id: K }> }

type Type = TypeGen
/* type Type = {
    "animal.dog": "id" | "foo";
    "animal.cat": "id" | "bar";
} */

But key remapping is more straightforward.
Playground link to code
